# Programatically change "Reject call with message"

Tags: android

I'd like to change the messages in the list "Reject call with message" according to the calling number (whether I have it in my contacts or if it has a certain carrier, etc) or even hide this option completely for some numbers.

What I'm asking for is a starting point since I couldn't find anything on developer.android.com nor on the internet.

**Note:** I don't want to reject or mute a call, no, I just want to modify the "Reject call with message" list on the fly depending on the caller or even disable it completely for some numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick response messages can only be altered through Call settings UI as the values are stored in Phone app's shared preference, **respond_via_sms_prefs.xml**. See [RespondViaSmsManager.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/master/src/com/android/phone/RespondViaSmsManager.java):

```
/** SharedPreferences file name for our persistent settings. */
private static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME = "respond_via_sms_prefs";


public void setInCallScreenInstance(InCallScreen inCallScreen) {
    mInCallScreen = inCallScreen;

    if (mInCallScreen != null) {
        // Prefetch shared preferences to make the first canned response lookup faster
        // (and to prevent StrictMode violation)
        mInCallScreen.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

Only Phone app can read/write from/to the file.

Default values are set in [respond_via_sms_settings.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/master/res/xml/respond_via_sms_settings.xml).

As far as I can tell, what you are trying to achieve is not feasible at this moment.